# Get list of all users of a public group that match criteria A or criteria B or both

Tags: apex, soql, query, subquery

I have a public group comprising six users:

| UserOrGroupId | IsActive |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | true |
| 002 | false |
| 003 | true |
| 004 | false |
| 005 | false |
| 006 | true |

I would like to retrieve a list containing all active group members and the group member with id `005`, i.e.:

| UserOrGroupId | IsActive |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | true |
| 003 | true |
| 005 | false |
| 006 | true |

**My attempts:**

- Attempt 1: Querying `GroupMember`.

```
[SELECT UserOrGroupId
    FROM GroupMember
    WHERE UserOrGroupId in (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true) OR UserOrGroupId = '123'];
```

This yields the error: `Semi join sub-selects are not allowed with the 'OR' operator`

- Attempt 2: Querying `User`.

```
[SELECT Id
    FROM User 
    WHERE (Id in (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId = '00G5O000001BELo') AND IsActive = true) OR GroupId = '00G5O000001BELo'];
```

This yields a similar error: `Semi join sub-selects are only allowed at the top level WHERE expressions and not in nested WHERE expressions.`

- Attempt 3: Using a binding variable

```
List<User> activeUsers = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true];

List<GroupMember> groupUsers = [SELECT UserOrGroupId
                                FROM GroupMember
                                WHERE UserOrGroupId in :activeUsers OR UserOrGroupId = '0052P000000USlsQAG'];
```

This runs but returns the wrong output (a list of length 245).

**Could someone please shed some light on what this error means?**

I know that that OR cannot be used with subqueries (see [Subquery limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#:%7E:text=You%20can%E2%80%99t%20use%20subqueries%20with%20OR.)), but I'm not sure what else to use.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/165275) suggests splitting up the queries and then merging the results. However, I'm unable to do that in this case, as I need to preserve the order of group members in the output.

Comment: for attempt 1: if UserOrGroupId = '123'  is id of the user   then you do not have to use  or condition   you can modify subquery itself like  SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true  or id='123'.   if   you want to follow answer which suggests merging of result  ,  order  can be preserved  if you use a list.   make a list  with first filter.   get another list with rows to remove based on additional filter and remove those elements by iterating first list

Comment: note that a group member can be users in a role or role & subordinates - this inevitably drives one to apex. and multiple queries with intermediate data structures